# Problems Installing pip on CentOS 5.x

Tags: python, centos, pip

I have pip installed:

```
[amr@h2oamr kits]$ python get-pip.py
Requirement already up-to-date: pip in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

However, I'm getting this error when trying to install Django:

```
[amr@h2oamr kits]$ pip install django
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 7, in ?
    from pip import main
ImportError: No module named pip
```

I am stuck trying to move forward. I installed pip as recommended by using a `get-pip.py` module I downloaded.

This upgrade also did not work.

```
[amr@h2oamr kits]$ pip install --upgrade pip
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 7, in ?
    from pip import main
ImportError: No module named pip
```

How can I remove pip altogether, and then re-install it?

Comment: Try updating your pip with `pip install --upgrade pip`

Comment: Thanks @TheGirrafish Unsuccessful, and I updated the info in OP.

Answer (score -1):

you can use the command *$ rm pip* to remove pip and then *$sudo apt-get install pip* to get the latest version

Comment: I'm on RHEL, so it would have to be yum, and that hasn't work. How does `rm` uninstall?

Comment: It directly removes the directory with the file